# Ms Teams: How to know the organization/company name in which my bot is installed

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am using nodejs sdk v4 to develop the bot. I want to add the company to my database as soon as they  install my bot.

Comment: you can try [Get Organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph API

Comment: Just be aware that the answer above means you have an app installed and configured (i.e. consented to), so it's not a totally out of the box "bot" scenario. The best you'll get without that is a tenant id, which is sent for every event/message to the bot (doesn't give you a name, but at least helps you identify which tenant each user/message comes from)